# Add quotes to strings between commas shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a string like

```
1,2,A,N,53,3,R,R,^A,-C,-T,2,S,9,l,8,8Z,sl,138Z,l,Y,75680,P
```

Now, I am trying to achieve below string

```
1,2,A,N,53,3,R,R,"^A,-C,-T",2,S,9,l,8,8Z,sl,138Z,l,Y,75680,P
```

So, I am trying to replace everything after 8th occurrence of comma (,)  from start and before 12th occurrence of comman (,) from end to be in quotes.

I tried some options of awk but unable to achieve it . Anyway to get this done .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
awk -v s1="\"" -F, '{$9=s1 $9;$(NF-12)=$(NF-12) s1} 1' OFS=,   Input_file
```

So here I am making a variable which is " and making field separator as comma. Then I am re-creating 9th field as per your requirement with s1 and $9. Then re-creating 13th field from last(point to be noted no hardcoding of field number here so it may have any number of fields) and adding s1's value in last of it's current value. Then mentioning 1 will print the line. Setting OFS(output field separator) as comma too.

Answer (score 1):

```
x='1,2,A,N,53,3,R,R,^A,-C,-T,2,S,9,l,8,8Z,sl,138Z,l,Y,75680,P'

awk -F, -v OFS=,  -v q='"' '{$9=q $9;$11=$11 q}1' <<< "$x"
1,2,A,N,53,3,R,R,"^A,-C,-T",2,S,9,l,8,8Z,sl,138Z,l,Y,75680,P
```

Explanation: Here `FS` and `OFS` are set to comma as the input stream is CSV.double quote is stored in a variable named `q`.  Then the value of the desired columns are altered to get the desired results. You can change the values of columns to get any other results.

For files:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=,  -v q='"' '{$9=q $9;$11=$11 q}1' inputfile
```

Comment: so instead of assigning the string to variable if I pass it as a txt file will it work same way . As wanted to know if multiple lines are passed together.

Comment: This is counting fields from front .. I was counting 9th from front and 12th from back ..

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v FS=',' -v OFS=',' '{$9="\"" $9;$11=$11"\""; print}' your_file
1,2,A,N,53,3,R,R,"^A,-C,-T",2,S,9,l,8,8Z,sl,138Z,l,Y,75680,P
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/,/&"/8;s/,/"&/11' file
```

Insert `"` after and before `'` eight and eleven.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/\^A,-C,-T/,"\42^A,-C,-T\42")}1' file

1,2,A,N,53,3,R,R,"^A,-C,-T",2,S,9,l,8,8Z,sl,138Z,l,Y,75680,P
```

The fine point here is to escape the caret.